# iOS 8 popoverpresentationcontroller popoverlayoutmargin not working

Tags: ios

I am using the new `popOverPresentationController` to present `UIPopOverController` in iOS 8.
I set the `popOverLayoutMargins` with a value like *{65.0, 10.0, 45.0, 10.0}*.
But these do not reflect when I present the popOverController. This used to work perfectly on iOS 7.
Is this broken on ios 8?

Regards,
Harikant Jammi

Comment: This seems to be a bug which has been around since the iOS8 betas. There is some discussion on the apple dev forums here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1045909

Comment: Any updates on this..? is it fixed in iOS 8.3 ?

Answer (score 16):

It is an Apple bug which has not yet been fixed.  References to the bug can be found in this [example code](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch09p476popovers/ch22p751popovers/ViewController.swift) and on the Apple [developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1045909).

There is currently no clear workaround for this issue.  A bug report with ID **18392444** has been filed with Apple.

Comment: Has anyone checked this in ios 8.1?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working in iOS 10 either. Any workarounds?

Comment: or iOS 12 can you believe it!

Answer (score 0):

It works on iOS 13 now.

I guess the arrow point origin maybe follow this expressions

```
let xRatio = (permittedArrowDirections is horizonal) ? 1/2 : 1
let yRatio = (permittedArrowDirections is vertical) ? 1/2 : 1

x =  sourceRect.origin.x + sourceRect.size.width * xRatio + popoverLayoutMargins.left
y =  sourceRect.origin.y + sourceRect.size.height * yRatio + popoverLayoutMargins.top
```