# Xcode, Swift: How to center popover box

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, popover

Link to my github account with files, simply download zip: https://github.com/jzhang172/modalTest

When I click on the "popover" link, I would like to center the popover in the center of the screen.

I tried referencing some stackoverflow questions such as: 
[how to center a popoverview in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759615/how-to-center-a-popoverview-in-swift)

but no luck.  I'm a noob in swift and I'm only using swift, not objective C.

Screenshot of what I see:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Replacing

```
controller?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.layer.bounds.height * 0.5,0.0,0.0)
```

with

```
controller?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.layer.bounds.width * 0.5, self.view.layer.bounds.height * 0.5,0.0,0.0)
```

will center the popover content horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You can center the `UIPopover` in your view with the code below.

```
let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController
controller?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
controller?.sourceView = self.view
controller?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(0.0, self.view.layer.bounds.height * 0.5,0.0,0.0)
vc.preferredContentSize=CGSize(width: 400, height: 200)
```

Comment: Thank you, question though, it seems to only work if the size of the popover is as I set it, but if I set the last line to:vc.preferredContentSize=CGSize(width: 300, height: 100), it is center vertically but not horizontally, any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let popoverPresentationController = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController {
        let controller = popoverPresentationController
        controller.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
        controller.sourceView = self.view
        controller.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5 - 200, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.5 - 100, width: 400, height: 200)
        segue.destination.preferredContentSize=CGSize(width: 400, height: 200)
    }
}
```